# php: json from ajax call containing single quotes not showing in html

Tags: php, ajax, json, multidimensional-array

I'm using an ajax call to receive a multidimensional JSON array constructed through complex queries. Some of the values in the arrays contain text with apostrophes. A simplified JSON sample of the data received:

```
{"rows":
    {"51314":
         {"id":"1020","text":"O’Conner"},
     "51315":
         {"id":... etc etc
```

The data is echoed directly onto the page through the headers to construct table content, so it's not really an option to process it after it's been received by the client, at least not the way I see it, but maybe it's possible?

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($this->data);
```

The data shows correctly in the server response text as shown above, but all text after the apostrophe is not being displayed on the screen! Any ideas on how to fix this?*

This is what I've tried so far:

```
echo json_decode(str_replace("'", "\'", json_decode($this->data)));
```

addslashes() expects strings, not arrays, and similar with htmlspecialchars().

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit**

1) On closer inspection it is actually single quotes (**'**) (a.k.a. typewriter apostrophes) that's causing the problem. I guess my English is not perfect. Sorry about that. I've changed the title accordingly. A better example is:

"text":"SIMA'S".

Comment: What are you using to display the data? If you are seeing correct data in the server response (via debug console I assume) then the problem is probably in the display code.

Comment: Good call. See my updated answer. This was actually my first hunch as well, but then I posted the question because I thought it might be a general issue with single quotes. Turned out not to be.

Answer (score 1):

This is what finally worked for me.

Before adding content to the multidimensional array, I added the following lines of code:

```
        if (strpos($text, "'")) {
            $_t = str_replace("'", "&#39", $text); 
            $text = $_t;
        }
```

I also tried using addslashes() and htmlspecialchars(), but that didn't work.

**Edit**
It actually turned out to be a display bug in the third-party jQuery application I was using, but hopefully the above code can be of use to someone facing similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

The problems that your replacement is using the wrong character. You're replacing ' (single quote) instead of ` (apostrophe).

To be sure you should probably replace both, but only do the brutal version if you're confident that your library always uses double quotes to enclose strings.

Also, the JSON you've pasted in does not appear to be valid. I added whitespace to show the structure but that revealed structural problems.

Comment: Well spotted. I've removed the superfluous comma in the JSON and changed the title accordingly. And yes, my best bet so far is to loop through the inner arrays and do a replace.

Answer (score 0):

The `’` is not a standard ASCII quote, but something that probably needs UTF-8 encoding. You should start by adding a `; charset=UTF-8` to your `Content-Type`, and check that things are properly encoded. I would be surprised if it caused it to stop mid-sentence like I did, I'd rather expect it to throw an error and not do anything...

Beyond that, without the client-side code and some debugging traces, it's difficult to say much more...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did try changing the charset to UTF-8, but unfortunately it didn't do the trick. And you would be surprised if it caused...what? :)